# How do I configure embedded MongoDB with authentication for use in spring boot integration tests?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a spring boot application that is using MongoDB for persistence. I'm putting together integration tests, and I'm using the [flapdoodle embedded mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) library for the embedded DB.

This is coupled with spring boots auto-configure and everything works wonderfully for integration tests. As soon as I add authentication credentials for MongoDB, however, everything falls apart.

My understanding is that spring auto-configure finds the credentials and attempts to connect to the database with authentication, which fails, because it's an embedded database that hasn't been initialized with credentials yet.

I've attempted to use [mongeez](https://github.com/mongeez/mongeez) in order to initialize the credentials pre-spring startup, but this library has the same issue with credentials sensing.

So my real question:

Is there a way to initialize the embedded database with authentication? I've been digging through the source code and haven't found anything.

Comment: Could you add the current config for prod as well as integ-tests?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Would love to know if/when this gets answered. I'm getting com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential

Comment: @user26270, unfortunately I never found a way to do this. What I had to do instead was remove the credentials from the configuration altogether and add them at runtime during the production deploy. So the integration tests will not be able to test the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is how it works for me (using Kotlin):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = ["spring.data.mongodb.port="])
class IntegrationTests {

@Autowired
private val webClient: WebTestClient? = null

@Autowired
private val mongoConfig: IMongodConfig? = null
var collection: MongoCollection<Document>? = null

fun createDBAndCollection(collectionName: String){
    val mongo = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", mongoConfig!!.net().port)
    val db = mongo.getDatabase("local")
    db.createCollection(collectionName)
    collection = db.getCollection(collectionName)
}

@Test
fun `Find all tracks on JSON REST endpoint`() {
    createDBAndCollection("track")
    collection?.insertOne(Document("key", "val"))

    webClient!!.get().uri("/reactive/tracks")
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful
            .expectBodyList<Track>()
            .hasSize(1);
}
}
```

- No need to change application.properties. Its enough to empty the port setting using the SprintBootTest Annotation (other approaches did not work for me, like e.g. @TestPropertySource)
- mongoConfig is injected and used to retrieve the random port generated by flapdoodle
- the database name must match the one in application.properties (I am sure there is a way to read this dynamically at runtime though).

My gradle test dependencies are:

```
testImplementation('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create an authenticated user by looking at you `admin.system.users` collection. Just create a test user and put it there with the mongo client. As soon as you have a user there you can dump that document and use that json to create a new authenticated user in your embedded mongo test suite. It would be something like this:

```
private static void createAuthorizationUser() {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(HOST);
    MongoDatabase admin = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
    MongoCollection<Document> usersCollection = admin.getCollection("system.users");
    usersCollection.insertOne(Document.parse(""
            + "{\n" + 
            "    \"_id\": \"admin.test-user\",\n" + 
            //"    \"userId\": Binary(\"rT2Ig**********jGXZEQ==\", 4),\n" + 
            "    \"user\": \"test-user\",\n" + 
            "    \"db\": \"admin\",\n" + 
            "    \"credentials\": {\n" + 
            "        \"SCRAM-SHA-1\": {\n" + 
            "            \"iterationCount\": 10000,\n" + 
            "            \"salt\": \"gmm******GnNcAw==\",\n" + 
            "            \"storedKey\": \"qE***********8/LAvG7s=\",\n" + 
            "            \"serverKey\": \"Re*********eQh6w=\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "    },\n" + 
            "    \"roles\": [\n" + 
            "        {\n" + 
            "            \"role\": \"readWrite\",\n" + 
            "            \"db\": \"test\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "    ]\n" + 
            "}"
            + ""));
}
```

I've created a user named test-user that has readWrite privileges over test db. For some reason the embedded Mongo does not like the Binary function, but just commenting it does not hurt the authentication feature.

When creating a client you can do simply through

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
    new MongoClientURI( 
        String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s", "test-user", "****", "localhost", 27017, "admin" ) 
    )
);
```

It should fix the problem.